# What does this transformer symbol mean

Tags: transformer, symbol

In a balun I have, (model 50-7725 from CPC, datasheet -> http://www.farnell.com/datasheets/2365902.pdf?_ga=2.142463986.1590159842.1535980880-667311346.1535980880)

It shows the Balun as: 
[image]

What is the see through circle on the signal line, to the left, which connects to ground, mean?

Answer (score 2):

That's not part of the transformer, it's part of the connector. It's showing you that the RCA connector is coaxial, with ground on the outer conductor and signal on the inner conductor.

Comment: Thanks for the info !!! any ideas how this is actually a Balun then? it looks to me it's common mode, so I don't understand how it's going from unbalanced to balanced (left to right)